# Postgresql INSERT is asking for primary key value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Running Postgres 9.6.6. I created a table as follows:

```
create table person (
id serial primary key,
name text,
role integer references role (id),
phonenumber text);
```

When I try to insert data as follows:

```
insert into person values ('This Person',2,'+15105551111');
```

I get this message:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: 'This Person'
```

which suggests that Postgres is expecting a value for `id`.  But if `id` is a serial primary key, shouldn't it be autopopulating and autoincrementing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not specify the column names, the values will be applied to the first `n` columns in the table. Thus `'This Person'` will be applied to `id`, and thus the error you're getting. You can (should) specify the columns names in order to avoid this problem:

```
INSERT INTO person
(name, role, phonenumber) -- Here
VALUES ('This Person', 2, '+15105551111');
```

Comment: ok, but I have another table `role` with an `id` primary key and only one other column `role`, and i can successfully add data with e.g. `insert into role values ('XYZ');`.  So does this only apply to tables with more than one non-(primary key) column?

Comment: No. In the table you mention, `id` is probably the second column.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the table definition, you'll see that the column is actually defined like this:

```
id integer DEFAULT nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass)
```

This is because `serial` is only a shorthand.

That means that the auto-generated value is only used if no value is explicitly inserted. But since your `INSERT` statement has no column list, you actually insert to *all* columns, so the first value will be inserted into the first column, which leads to the error.

You can either explicitly list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO person (name, role, phonenumber)
   VALUES ('This Person', 2, '+15105551111');
```

or you can use `DEFAULT` to specify that the default value should be used:

```
INSERT INTO person
   VALUES (DEFAULT, 'This Person', 2, '+15105551111');
```

The first solution is better because it is always good to be explicit about the columns (tables can get altered).

Comment: see my comment on Mureinik's answer